# ¿Como arregla en update y el upgrade en ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Ayer intente hacer un update en la terminal de ubuntu 17.04 y me dio este resultado

sudo apt-get update

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Obj:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release                                                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                                                
Obj:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                      
Ign:7 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease              
Obj:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/security/ubuntu zesty InRelease            
Err:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:10 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:11 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

¿Alguien sabe la manera de solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya no hay soporte para Zesty desde hace poco, así que o bien te pasas a otra versión/distro o tienes que cambiar los repositorios para que apunten a old-releases:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Pero cuidado! este portal es para consultas sobre programación, nos van a reñir a los dos, a ti por preguntar y a mi por responder.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias.

No sabia eso, no volverá a ocurrir.